# Angular2 - Main child route not working

Tags: typescript, angular

Here's the config of my child routes:

```
export const ProjectRouter: RouterConfig = [
  { path: 'projects', component: MainProjectComponent,
    children: [
      { path: 'new', component: NewProjectComponent, canActivate: [AuthRouter] },
      { path: ':id', component: ProjectComponent, canActivate: [AuthRouter] },
      { path: '', component: ProjectsComponent, canActivate: [AuthRouter] }
    ] }
];
```

MainProjectComponent:

```
@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  template: '<router-outlet></router-outlet>',
  directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES]
})
export class MainProjectComponent {}
```

The route to "/project/new" or "/projects/:id" are working, but when I go to "/projects" it doesn't show the ProjectsComponent (it's basically a list).

No errors, just an empty router-outlet.
I don't what I'm missing here...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a bug on version alpha.3. After updating to beta.2 everything worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `pathMatch: 'full'` to the empty path route:

```
{ path: '', component: ProjectsComponent, canActivate: [AuthRouter] , pathMatch: 'full'}
```